# Merge all Excel files from each subfolder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master folder named 2022, (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\2022). In this folder there are subfolders of only one level. In each subfolder there are Excel files.

I need to merge all Excel files from each subfolder. A merged file should be created for each subfolder and each merged file should contain only one sheet. Data must be collected from sheet 1 of each Excel file.

```vb
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    
    Dim MasterFolder As String, SubFolder As String, FileName As String
    Dim MergeFile As Workbook, CurrentFile As Workbook
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet, MergeSheet As Worksheet
    
    'Set the path of the master folder
    MasterFolder = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\2022\"
    
    'Loop through all subfolders in the master folder
    SubFolder = Dir(MasterFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While SubFolder <> ""
        If SubFolder <> "." And SubFolder <> ".." Then
            'Create a new workbook to store the merged data
            Set MergeFile = Workbooks.Add
            Set MergeSheet = MergeFile.Sheets(1)
            
            'Loop through all excel files in the subfolder
            FileName = Dir(MasterFolder & SubFolder & "\*.xlsx*")
            Do While FileName <> ""
                'Open the current file and copy data from sheet 1
                Set CurrentFile = Workbooks.Open(MasterFolder & SubFolder & "\" & FileName)
                Set CurrentSheet = CurrentFile.Sheets(1)
                CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=MergeSheet.Range("A" & MergeSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
                CurrentFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
                FileName = Dir()
            Loop
            
            'Save the merged data to a new file
            MergeFile.SaveAs Filename:=MasterFolder & SubFolder & "\" & SubFolder & "_Merged.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            MergeFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        SubFolder = Dir()
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Merging completed successfully!"
    
End Sub
```

The first merged file for the first subfolder is created but when it should go to the next one, the Excel application closes without an error message.

Comment: You try to use 2 nested `Dir` - loops: That doesn't work in VBA. When you issue the inner `Dir` (to fetch the file names), you are "destroying" the outer loop. The command to fetch the next folder `SubFolder = Dir()` will always fail. You should consider to use the `fileSystemObject` instead.

Comment: Are there subfolders of only one level? I mean, does such a subfolder have subfolders, too?

Comment: Subfolders of only one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Mr. FunThomas, the code below use fileSystemObject

```
Sub test()
Dim MasterFolder As String
Dim fs, subF, subFiles, FL
Dim MergeFile As Workbook, MergeSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MasterFolder = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\2022\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each subF In fs.GetFolder(MasterFolder).SubFolders
        Set subFiles = fs.GetFolder(subF).Files
        Set MergeFile = Workbooks.Add
        Set MergeSheet = MergeFile.Sheets(1)
            For Each FL In subFiles
                Workbooks.Open FL
                With ActiveWorkbook
                    .Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=MergeSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Close SaveChanges:=False
                End With
            Next FL
        With MergeFile
            .SaveAs Filename:=subF & "\" & subF.Name & "_Merged.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next subF

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```